# Function parameters accept everything

Tags: c#, .net

Im quite new to C# and was wondering if it's possible to pass something to a function which is undefined / different each time, like the example below ;

```
string stringexam = "string"
```

or

```
int intexam = 5;
```

or

```
bool exam = false;
```

etc..

```
Myfunction(stringexam);

Myfunction(intexam);

Myfunction(exam);

public static void MyFunction(accepteverything) {

//DO SOMETHING

}
```

How could something like this be achieved ?
I need this because then I could use something like this in my code :

```
MyFunction(1,"ok example 1");
MyFunction(2, 22);
MyFunction(3, false);
```

Then I could continue in the MyFunction :

```
MyFunction(int method, accepteverything?!) 
{
    if(method == 1) {
      ContinueExample1(string accepteverything); // CALLS FUNCTION CONTINUEEXAMPLE1 WHICH NEEDS A STRING AS PARAMETER
    } 
    if(method == 2) {
       ContinueExample2(int accepteverything); // CALLS FUNCTION CONTINUEEXAMPLE2 WHICH NEEDS A INT AS PARAMETER
    }
    if(method == 3) {
       ContinueExample3(bool accepteverything);
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll have to create a constructor for each signature.

Comment: Just because you *can* doesn't mean you *should*

Comment: Sounds like you should investigate Method Overloading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use Generic functions. This avoids boxing/Unboxing too

```
public void MyFunction<T>(int method, T acceptEverything)
{
    switch(method)
    {
        case 1: ContinueExample1(acceptEverything as string); //String parameter
                break;

        case 2: ContineExample2(Convert.ToInt32(acceptEverything)); //int parameter 
                break;
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Call like this

```
MyFunction(1,stringexam);
MyFunction(2,intexam);
```

Comment: That is not going to compile, `ContinueExample1` takes in a `string` not `T` so you are going to get a compiler error. You could do `case 1: ContinueExample1((string)acceptEverything);`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Correctd that

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with method overloads, the same named function but with different parameter types.

```
void MyFunction(string accepteverything) 
{
    ContinueExample1(accepteverything);
}
void MyFunction(int accepteverything) 
{
    ContinueExample2(accepteverything);
}
void MyFunction(bool accepteverything) 
{
    ContinueExample3(accepteverything);
}
```

This lets you do

```
string stringexam = "string"
int intexam = 5;
bool exam = false;

MyFunction(stringexam);
MyFunction(intexam);
MyFunction(exam);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the behavior of the method is the same no matter what type is passed in, you could pretty easily make the method:

```
public void MyFunction(int method, object acceptEverything)
{
    switch(method)
    {
        case 1: ContinueExample1(acceptEverything as string);
                break;

        case 2: ContineExample2(acceptEverything as int);
                break;
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Unfortunately that is going to introduce a lot of boxing and unboxing.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you could. But you probably want to rethink the way you're going about things. Wanting to reduce the code you have to write is good.

> > Bill Gates — 'I choose a lazy person to do a hard job. Because a lazy person will find an easy way to do it.'

But it's not always necessary, and can introduce unneeded complexity to something that otherwise is simple and self-explanatory.

Think about what's going on in your code. You have an exam which you want to do something with. Presumably you're concerned that there might be more than one way to identify a given exam for different users. But, whatever it is you want to do is probably not going to change. So, let's attack from that angle: we need to be able to identify an exam given some unknown parameter.

```
public Exam FindExamFromAnything(object input)
{
    int examID = 0;
    if (int.TryParse(input.ToString(), out examID))
    {
        return GetExamFromID(examID);
    }
    else
    {
        return GetExamFromName(input.ToString());
    }

}


public Exam GetExamFromID(int ID)
{
    // get the Exam with the right ID from a database or something
}

public Exam GetExamFromName(string examName)
{
    // get the Exam with the right name from a database
}
```

Now you've got a method that you can pass whatever, and you'll get back the thing you were looking for. Great!

Except... two years from now somebody has a list of students that took a given exam, and tries to use your method:

```
List<string> students = new List<string> {"Alice","Bob"};
var exam = FindExamFromAnything(students); // nope!
```

Doesn't work. But how would he know? There's nothing in the signature that specifies what to use as the object. Now he's got to locate your source code, or use trial and error, to figure out how to use your API. Your documentation might explain that it only takes an int or a string, but...

Instead, it's not really that much more work to write a second method. As [Scott Chamberlain points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35563486/3845456) you can overload a method name to take different parameters. A better solution *for this implementation* is to get more specific; I'm partial to methods like above exposed, that is, expose your `GetExamFromString` and `GetExamFromID` and whatever else you need, so they are self explanatory.